# Only output value if x > y in awk

Tags: awk, aix

INPUT:

```
0:root@server:/root # vmstat 60 2

System configuration: lcpu=52 mem=131072MB ent=10.00

kthr    memory              page              faults              cpu          
----- ----------- ------------------------ ------------ -----------------------
 r  b   avm   fre  re  pi  po  fr   sr  cy  in   sy  cs us sy id wa    pc    ec
 5  0 13254063 12378057   0   0   0   0    0   0 3411 22516 9063 10  2 88  0  1.94  19.4
 5  0 13341251 12290955   0   0   0   0    0   0 3507 20192 9062  9  2 89  0  1.88  18.8
0:root@server:/root #
```

NEEDED OUTPUT:

```
0
```

It is zero, since the average r < lcpu. The "id" values are not important in this case.

another INPUT:

```
0:root@server:/root # vmstat 60 2

System configuration: lcpu=52 mem=131072MB ent=10.00

kthr    memory              page              faults              cpu          
----- ----------- ------------------------ ------------ -----------------------
 r  b   avm   fre  re  pi  po  fr   sr  cy  in   sy  cs us sy id wa    pc    ec
 52  0 13254063 12378057   0   0   0   0    0   0 3411 22516 9063 10  2 6  0  1.94  19.4
 53  0 13341251 12290955   0   0   0   0    0   0 3507 20192 9062  9  2 4  0  1.88  18.8
0:root@server:/root #
```

NEEDED OUTPUT:

```
95
```

It is 95, because the average r > lcpu. 
And it is 95, because id means idle, but we need the cpu consumption. So 6+4 is the idle value, the average from them is 5. So 100-5 = 95% is the cpu load.

Average is needed in the "r"'s too! Not just in "id". In the last example it is 52.5, so it was greater than 52.

This is a general UNIX problem to measure CPU consumption. If r > lcpu and the cpu usage % is very high, then we have a CPU bottleneck.

It is interesting that there is no solution for the processing of the vmstat output, that's why I'm asking the awk grandmasters about it.

**Question**: So I need something like this: "vmstat 60 2 | GODLY-AWK-MAGIC-HERE"

For more details, please see (I couldn't find a better link):

http://aix4admins.blogspot.com/2011/09/vmstat-t-5-3-shows-3-statistics-in-5.html

> If runnable threads (r) divided by the number of CPU is greater than
>   one -> possible CPU bottleneck

Comment: Am I correct in the assumption that all the info you need is in line 2 and 7 and 8 of the output? Or can there be more of these long lines with numbers at the end?

Comment: It may be helpful to write out what you want in pseudo-code, also to let us know what might change and what is constant. It's pretty confusing at the moment (partially because the headers don't line up). e.g. `if the average of (field #1 of column 8 and 9) >…`

Comment: Definitely can appreciate the obvious effort you made to be clear, but I agree with @Sparhawk; not 100% sure which numbers you are trying to parse.  Give some pseudocode, or plain English, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very crude:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { d = -1 }
    /lcpu/ { lcpu = substr($3, 6); next }
    $1 == "r" { ++d; next }
    d < 0 { next }
    {
        ++d
        r += $1
        id += $16
        next
    }
    END {
        if (r / d > lcpu)
            print 100 - id / d
        else
            print 0
    }
'
```

or if you like:

```
awk '
    /lcpu/ { lcpu=substr($3, 6) }
    $1 ~ /[0-9]+/ {
        ++d
        r += $1
        id += $16
        next
    }
    END {
        print (r/d>lcpu) ? 100 - id / d : 0
    }
'
```

to:

```
awk '/lcpu/{lcpu=substr($3,6)}$1~/[0-9]+/{++d;r+=$1;id+=$16;next;}END{print(r/d>lcpu)?100-id/d:0}'
```

Does it give the results you want?